# getting invalid hindi string from mysql using jsp

Tags: mysql, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, odbc

```
here are the settings

this time using odbc connection

![showing u the settings][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4f2bD.jpg

and

![ i have mentioned utf8 here][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9fo5.jpg

here is my code


<%-- 
Document   : index.jsp
Created on : 30 Aug, 2011, 10:57:05 AM
Author     : Sahil
--%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import = "java.sql.*;"%>
<%@page import = "java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*"%> 
<%@page import= "java.lang.RuntimePermission" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Punjabi-Hindi Dictionary | Output</title>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8">  
    <%

    try
      { 
       if (request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) 
           request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       Connection cn;

       Statement st;
       ResultSet rs;
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:myodbc","root","");
       st=cn.createStatement();   
       rs=st.executeQuery("select * from stu_info");
       while(rs.next()){
       String Name= rs.getString("Name");

     %> 
     <%=Name%>
     <br>
      <%
                        }
     rs.close();
     st.close();
     cn.close();
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
      out.println(ex.getMessage());
     }
      %>

    </form>    
    </body>
  </html>

  this time it gives me diffrent output

  à¤¸à¤¾à¤¹à¤¿à¤²
  à¤¸à¤¾à¤¹à¤¿à¤²à¤¸à¤¾à¤¹à¤¿à¤²
```

Comment: i don't know why i amnot able to see the images

Comment: i have used column datatype varchar(50) and collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ?????? instead of Hindi text from MySQL database using JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318757/getting-instead-of-hindi-text-from-mysql-database-using-jsp)

Answer (score -1):

Obviously your output is in a single page encoding (e.g. ISO-8859-1) and not in UTF-8, this can have several reasons:

- Have you checked the data is correctly stored in your database? If not, you should check if the table you use for storing the data is UTF-8
- Is your database connection properly set up to use UTF-8? I don't know how this is done for odbc, but for the mysql-jdbc Driver you might need to append this to your configuration url:

  characterEncoding=utf-8

Comment: this u can suggest me in a comment.

Comment: in datasources odbs there is a feild charset.i have selected utf-8 there

Comment: please post the url you use to connect to your database (again, I don't now about odbc, the config is for a jdbc connection)

Comment: i have given some values in the interface of ODBC       Datasourcename = myodbc , description= ,    server= localhost , user = root , password = , database = student

Comment: and i have given characterset = utf8

Comment: sorry, but you have just posted two dialog boxes without any context. And again my hint is concerning jdbc not odbc (which I would suggest to use to connect to the database, as using odbc usually only is an option if there's no proper jdbc driver available.)